# Font Awesome spinners icons not spinning in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using spinner icon as below but i do't know why it is not spinning. It just work like a normal icon.

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new IconButton(
      // Use the FontAwesomeIcons class for the IconData
      icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.spinner), 
      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this moment, this package only provides the Icons, but those Icons do not spin or animate by themselves. Use flutter's animation capabilities to spin it. Here is example widget from [Brian Egan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8210363/brianegan).

```
class Spinner extends StatefulWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Duration duration;

  const Spinner({
    Key key,
    @required this.icon,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 1800),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SpinnerState createState() => _SpinnerState();
}

class _SpinnerState extends State<Spinner> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Widget _child;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    )..repeat();
    _child = Icon(widget.icon);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: _controller,
      child: _child,
    );
  }
}
```

Usage

```
Spinner(
  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.spinner,
)
```

related issue on [github](https://github.com/brianegan/font_awesome_flutter/issues/20)

Comment: If anyone looking for it to have start stop just add the following
`final bool isSpinning`
```
stopRotation() {
    _controller.stop();
  }

  startRotation() {
    _controller.repeat();
  }
```
```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.isSpinning ? startRotation() : stopRotation();
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

At this moment font_awesome_flutter package only provides the Icons, and those Icons do not spin or animate by themselves.

That's why i used a material design **circular progress indicator** which shows progress along a circle

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator/CircularProgressIndicator.html